# Command gotoIf and storeAlertPresent to one string in Selenium IDE. Correct me

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, alert, selenium-ide

Please correct command:

```
gotoIf | storeAlertPresent==false | continue
```

this is command doesn't works. And I can't use more then one string in Selenium IDE.

Comment: can you `storeAlertPresent` to a variable and use that variable to check `==false`?

Comment: no, after alert appears I have  only one action before `getAlert` or selenium will give fail with error.

Comment: is it not working for you if you do `gotoIf` immediately after `storeAlertPresent` line?

Comment: it is not working if I use some command different by `getAlert` if page has Alert.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
storeEval | try {selenium.getAlert()} catch(e){selenium.continueFromRow(gotoLabels['MYLABEL'])} | alert_message
```

**If alert is present it will** store your alert message to *alert_message* variable and close the alert.

**If alert is not present it will** send your test to 'MYLABEL'

Highly possible that there is an easier way to do it. But I hope it will help